# Path alias with typescript for express static folders?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, visual-studio-code

**Context:**

I have an express web server which I'm using as a sort of 'template' to create solutions for customers. The needs and use-cases of customers in the industry I work in are all somewhat similar, and therefore most static resources (images, es6 modules etc.) are shared between them. These are all in the root /static/ folder. There are cases where the customers needs necessitate individualized scripts and resources in which case I place them under their respective solution folder, e.g. solutions/solutionA/static/def.js for customer A. In server.js, the express launcher script, I set two static directories through middleware. /static (for shared stuff), and /solutions/ACTIVE SOLUTION/static (for solution specific stuff), where ACTIVE SOLUTION is a constant string specified at the top of the file.

```
node_modules/
static/
 abc.js
solutions/
 solutionA/
   static/
    def.ts
 solutionB/
   static/
    ghi.ts
 solutionC/
   static/
server.ts
tsconfig.json
```

**Problem:**

My problem lies with typescript complaining about es6 import statements. From within say solutions/solutionA/static/def.ts, I cannot do

```
import abc from "./abc.js"
```

even though this is correct in-browser, as I have set the root /static as a static folder.

Is there any way I can indicate to typescript via tsconfig.json or other means, that I would like it to also search in a particular directory for said files (in this case, the root /static?). I do not want the resulting js files to have their import paths changed, as /abc.js will indeed be valid due to the express middleware.

**Current situation:**

As the imports are correct when loaded in browser, my solution is currently "working". The issue lies in the fact both visual studio code and tsc rightfully complain of the incorrect import path. This is a fairly recent refactoring, the merging of like solutions to stop splintering. It seemed like a good idea, only now my entire project is littered with errors.... Other people are going to be working on my solution eventually, and I don't want to give them something with copious amounts of worrying warnings.